# iOSOpenDev with Xcode

Tags: xcode, tweak

I am new to iOSOpenDev Xcode and trying to create tweak using iOSOpenDev with Xcode when I try to install the tweak to device I am getting error like this how to overcome this error .

```
Preparing to run Xcode Build Phase...
Signing /Users/naveenp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VerifayaTest-djfbpvkrsjijkgawzucyzrrhfqtk/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/VerifayaTest.dylib with codesign... Done.
Copying /Users/naveenp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VerifayaTest-djfbpvkrsjijkgawzucyzrrhfqtk/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/VerifayaTest.dylib to package directory at /MacMiniBackup/Swift/VerifayaTest/VerifayaTest/Package/Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries...
Preparing to build package...
Setting control file /MacMiniBackup/Swift/VerifayaTest/VerifayaTest/Package/DEBIAN/control Version field to 1.0-1 using /MacMiniBackup/Swift/VerifayaTest/VerifayaTest/PackageVersion.plist... Done.
Building package ... xcodebuild: error: SDK "/Applications/Xcode 3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk" cannot be located.
ar: error: unable to find utility "ar", not a developer tool or in PATH
Failed to create Debian archive
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 72
```

Any tutorial on how to install tweak to device ?

Comment: Are you actually trying to use Xcode 3? Do you not have access to a recent machine to run Xcode 6?

Comment: @jshier I have 3 Xcodes in my system thats why the name is Xcode 3 .Its actually Xcode 5.0.1

Comment: Update to Xcode 5.1.1 and make sure you install the command lines tools with it.